# Merging 2 userdefined arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have to merge 2 arrays into one array , for that i have tried -

```
$TotalResult = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
```

But I am not getting the desired result with this function.

My 2 arrays are:

```
$arr1 = Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => facebook
        [search_count] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => yahoomail.com
        [search_count] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => google.com
        [search_count] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => rediff.com
        [search_count] => 2
    )
);

$arr2=Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => youtube
        [adclicks_count] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => hotmail
        [adclicks_count] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => facebook
        [adclicks_count] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => google.com
        [adclicks_count] => 3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => yahoomail
        [adclicks_count] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => stackoverflow
        [adclicks_count] => 1
    )
);
```

And I want the resulting array 3 as follows -

```
$arr3 = Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => facebook
        [search_count] => 1
    [adclicks_count] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => yahoomail.com
        [search_count] => 1
        [adclicks_count] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => google.com
        [search_count] => 1
        [adclicks_count] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => rediff.com
        [search_count] => 2
        [adclicks_count] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => youtube
        [search_count] => 0
        [adclicks_count] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => hotmail
        [search_count] => 0
        [adclicks_count] => 4
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => stackoverflow
        [search_count] => 0
        [adclicks_count] => 1
    )
);
```

Please suggest me the if any solution available in php.

Comment: In the array you want, how are you calculating `adclicks_count`? it seems rather arbitrary.

Comment: It's not clear how do you want to merge them. But since you have search terms in different array indexes, `array_merge` is not what you need, you have to merge it with a custom function

Comment: Sorry Jon just corrected my arrays.

Comment: In `$arr1` you have `yahoomail.com`, in `$arr2` you have `yahoomail`. How does `yahoomail` magically become `yahoomail.com` in `$arr3`? How do you account for the `.com` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple custom script can make the trick work

http://www.tehplayground.com/#7Uudu9PwY

```
$arr1 = array(
    array('search_terms' => 'facebook', 'search_count' => 1),
    array('search_terms' => 'whatever', 'search_count' => 4)
);


$arr2 = array(
    array('search_terms' => 'facebook', 'adclicks_count' => 2),
    array('search_terms' => 'whatever', 'adclicks_count' => 3)
);


$searchTermToData = array();

foreach ($arr1 as $element)
    $searchTermToData[$element['search_terms']] = $element;

foreach ($arr2 as $element)
    $searchTermToData[$element['search_terms']]['adclicks_count'] = $element['adclicks_count'];

// build result

$result = array_values($searchTermToData);
```

Comment: Your code is not totally perfect, but it helped me alot to get the right solution, and site http://www.tehplayground.com also very useful.